# Extremely rare widget updates in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, ios15

I have an app that displays a widget on the iPhone home screen. The function `getTimeline`, which processes new updates of the widget, has the following structure:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {    
    applyConfiguration(...)
    
    aCompletionHandler(...){ result in
        let entry = SimpleEntry(...)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
     }
}
```

Note that I used the `.atEnd` update policy to update the widget as soon as possible. **In iOS 14 this worked quite well** and the widget was updated about every 30 minutes. However, **since iOS 15**, the widget takes hours or **sometimes **a whole day** to be updated**. :(

When I install the app via Xcode on my own iOS 15 device, the widget updates about every half hour (as it was always in iOS 14 the case). But when I install the same app version via the App Store, it again updates very rare and unpredictable.

Does anyone have the same problem? (Maybe a bug in iOS 15?), or any advice on how I can make the updates more frequent and predictable?